# How can I make this office script faster?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-scripts

how could I make this recursive script faster?
RNumber in this code is calculated in the spreadsheet through a formula and checked after each iteration

I'm typically iterating down from numbers > 50000 and the script runs very very slow. As a result I added a variable iteration step however this is not ideal and still doesn't run fast.

Would really appreciate some help!

```
async function findMaxDrawdown(context: Excel.RequestContext, currentMonth: number ) {
  var maxAvailableMonth;
  var monthsCount;
  var monthsRange; 
  var dscrThreshold = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("DDSHEET1").getRange("B14");
  await context.sync();
  const end = 0;
  var finalTestVariable = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("DDSHEET2").getRange("B16")
  var precisionFactor = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("DDSHEET1").getRange("B18");
  numberMonths = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("DDSHEET1").getRange("B17")
  months.load("values");
  precisionFactor.load("values");
  finalTestVariable.load("values");
  dscrThreshold.load("values");
  numberMonths.load("values");
  await context.sync();
  maxAvailableMonth = months.values[0][currentMonth - 1];
  monthsCount = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("DDSHEET1").getRange("B17");
  monthsCount.load("values");
  await context.sync();
  console.log(currentMonth)
  for (let i = maxAvailableMonth; i > -1; i-= precisionFactor.values[0][0]) {
    if (currentMonth < numberMonths.values[0][0]-1) {
      if( i < precisionFactor.values[0][0]){
        i = 0
      } 
    }
    
    context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("DDSHEET2").getRange("D2").getOffsetRange(1, currentMonth).values = [
      [i]
    ];
    await context.sync();
    var currentMonthRNumber = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("DDSHEET2").getRange("D2").getOffsetRange(2, currentMonth);
    currentMonthRNumber.load("values");
    await context.sync();
    if (currentMonthRNumber.values[0][0] >= rNumberThreshold.values[0][0]) {
      if (currentMonth == monthsCount.values) 
      {
        return; 
      } 
      else 
      {
        await findMaxDrawdown(context, currentMonth + 1);
        var finalTest = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("DDSHEET2").getRange("D2").getOffsetRange(1, currentMonth + 1); 
        finalTest.load("values");
        await context.sync();
        finalTestVariable.load("values")
        await context.sync();
        if (finalTest.values[0][0] == finalTestVariable.values[0][0]){
          continue
        } else{
          if (finalTest.values[0][0] > finalTestVariable.values[0][0]) {
            return;
          }
          else {
          }
        }
        break 
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
      continue;
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code sample provided contains few missing references -- looks like its a partial script. Hence I can't fully test it. But I see couple of issues -

a. You are using an older version of the script. You might be better off starting over with a new script so we can offer better suggestion. The one you have is the async version, which is not the primary script model anymore. I think you'll find the new version much simpler to work with.

b. You are reading inside of a loop and doing a whole bunch of `context.sync()`. Each time you do that, it'll result in Excel server communication and will introduce lots of delay. You should try to read all you want beforehand and only do data processing inside of the loop. At the end of the loop, you can do updates and `context.sync()` to save the updates.

If you need further help, send us feedback through "help improve office link" at the bottom of Excel web and include your email. Or, post a simplified version of the script that is easier to read/understand.